# JQuery Getting Dynamically Created Select Value

Tags: php, jquery

I have been reviewing a lot of pages about this and can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

In an HTML page I am using PHP to dynamically create a dropdown box on the page like this:

```
$sel = '<select "id"="userPhones">';

foreach ($user_phones as $single_phone) 
{
$phoneId = $single_phone['id'];
$phoneNum = $single_phone['phone_num'];
if($single_phone['isdefault']=='1')
{
    $sel.="<option id=".$phoneId." selected='selected'>".$phoneNum."</option>";
}
else
{
    $sel.="<option id=".$phoneId.">".$phoneNum."</option>";
}
}
$sel .='</select>';
echo $sel;
```

I see the dropdown appear on the page without a problem and it all looks like it is working. But then later I try to use JQuery to get at the value of the dropdown to act on it by doing this:

```
phone_num = $('#userPhones :selected').val();
alert(phone_num);
```

For some reason whenever I try to get at the value I am getting an alert of "undefined" and not the value of the dropdown. I am sure this is being set because I have looked at he source of the page and I have checked with Firebug that the elements exist on the page. I have tried just using the ID of the dropdown and val(), I have tried using text() but cannot seem to grab anything. Can someone please tell me what on earth is going on here? I have been racking my brains about this for a while now.

Comment: Why are you quoting 'id' in the statement: `$sel = '<select "id"="userPhones">';`? Incidentally, jQuery works client-side, so it's the rendered (x)html we'd need to see to help out properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` field in the select element should not have quotes around it. It's not valid markup and so jQuery does not find it with that id.

Comment: That did it!! Thanks so much for putting an end to my torture!